# How can I enable WMTS to return tile without authorization?

Tags: geoserver, wmts, authentication

I am not fully familiar with how OAuth works in GeoServer. I certainly poked around Geofence settings and attempted to give my data-store and layer ALL read permissions and tried using the * and anonymous roles.

I even hired someone deeply knowledgeable about this. And we haven't been able to server vector tiles to our client app without authorization being required.

Can someone point me to the right answers? Or give me tips?

Comment: why did you install GeoFence if you don't want authentication to be used?

Comment: Great question. My contractor used a docker compose bundle from the official GeoNode github repo. I assumed there is a way to massage the auth settings. I had no idea what is involved in the nitty gritty of the tech stack settings/authentication set up

Comment: I'd get a better contractor, look on the GeoServer website for a list

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add a rule to Geoserver > Authentication > Filter Section
added a URL pattern "/gwc/service/**" with  "no security" checked and only "anonymous" active in the "chain filter" list.

That seemed to work!